# Насколько корректно регулярное выражение

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть регулярное выражение, которое должно пропускать строки только с символами от a-z (в разных регистрах), цифры от 0-9 и символы `(`, `)`, `.`. Порядок может быть разный. Насколько регулярное выражение  `/[^A-Za-z0-9\- ().]/` соответствует этим требованиям

Answer (score 1):

Ваше регулярное выражение имеет противоположный смысл и добавочные условия: оно принимает любые символы кроме перечисленных вами, а также кроме пробела и дефиса. Для ваших условий подходит `/[A-Za-z0-9().]/`.

Comment: Флаг `i` в `/[\w().]/i` лишний. `\w` – `[A-Za-z0-9_]` (в JavaScript и в других языках, где `\w` не поддерживает все соответствующие символы Юникода).

Comment: Да, точно, это у меня помутнение.

Comment: Более того,  `\w` нам не подходит, потому что `_` не разрешено.

Answer (score 1):

`/[^A-Za-z0-9\- ().]/` представляет собой *исключающий* (инвертированный, негативный) символьный класс и находит любой символ, отличный от букв латинского алфавита, цифр, дефиса, обычного пробела, круглых скобок и точки в *любом месте* строки.

Вам нужно "*регулярное выражение, которое должно пропускать строки только с символами от `a-z` (в разных регистрах), цифры от `0-9` и символы `(`, `)`, `.`*", то есть

```js
/^[A-Za-z0-9().]+$/
/^[A-Za-z0-9().]*$/
```

Квантификатор `*` находит ноль и более символов, `+` – один и более символов. `^` находит начало строки, а `$` – конец строки.

См. [пример использования регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/oSZ4Ua/1).